# Extend auto_ptr to release a C-style object

Tags: c++

I want to implement a RAII mechanism for a `net-snmp` C library `struct snmp_pdu` object.

That object is created with a method called `struct snmp_pdu* snmp_pdu_create(int type)` and released with a method `void snmp_free_pdu(struct snmp_pdu *obj)`.

What I have done is extend auto_ptr to call the method libname_free_obj in the destructor. Below is the code:

```
class auto_snmp_pdu : public std::auto_ptr<snmp_pdu>
{
  public:
   virtual ~auto_snmp_pdu()
   {
     snmp_free_pdu(get());
   }
};
```

**Is the above correect?**

## EDIT

I cannot use `unique_ptr` since I am using an old version of g++ and I am not authorized to update it.

Comment: `auto_ptr` has been deprecated for 6 years, and now completely gone from the standard library. Use `std::unique_ptr` instead. You won't have to inherit it.

Comment: Use `std::unique_ptr<snmp_pdu>` instead and don't use it as base class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a custom deleter with a std::unique\_ptr member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053351/how-do-i-use-a-custom-deleter-with-a-stdunique-ptr-member)

Comment: @AndreKampling - Not a dup. But SO definitely needs a "do this instead to avoid headaches" close reason.

Comment: You can use RAII without using smart pointers too, Then you have to provide a constructor, destructor and a pointer in the RAII class.

Comment: Dan, given your latest edit, I'd say to avoid `std::auto_ptr` and completely define  `auto_snmp_pdu` as its own class. At least that way your class will be future proof.

Comment: @Dan updated answer in the light of your old compiler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`auto_ptr` is deprecated and bug-prone. Use `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter. Here is one implementation:

```
#include <memory>
extern "C" {
    struct snmp_pdu;

    struct snmp_pdu* snmp_pdu_create(int type);
    void snmp_free_pdu(struct snmp_pdu *obj);
}

struct snmp_pdu_deleter
{
    void operator()(snmp_pdu* p) const noexcept {
        snmp_free_pdu(p);
    }
};
using snmp_pdu_ptr = std::unique_ptr<snmp_pdu, snmp_pdu_deleter>;

snmp_pdu_ptr create_snmp_pdu(int x) {
    return snmp_pdu_ptr(snmp_pdu_create(x));
}


int main()
{
    auto ptr = create_snmp_pdu(0);
}
```

> > but my compiler is pre-c++11

`unique_ptr` and `move` semantics are fairly easy to simulate:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern "C" {
    struct snmp_pdu {};

    void foo(snmp_pdu*) { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }

    struct snmp_pdu* snmp_pdu_create(int type) {
        return (snmp_pdu*)malloc(sizeof(snmp_pdu));
    }
    void snmp_free_pdu(struct snmp_pdu *obj) {
        free(obj);
    }
}

struct snmp_pdu_proxy
{
    struct mover { 
        mover(snmp_pdu*& impl_ref) : impl_ref_(impl_ref) {}
        snmp_pdu*& impl_ref_; 
        };

    snmp_pdu_proxy(int code) 
    : impl_(snmp_pdu_create(code))
    {}

    snmp_pdu_proxy(mover m) 
    : impl_(0)
    {
        std::swap(impl_, m.impl_ref_);
    }

    mover move() {
        return mover ( impl_ );
    }

    snmp_pdu_proxy& operator=(mover m)
    {
        snmp_pdu_proxy tmp = move();
        std::swap(m.impl_ref_, impl_);
        return *this;
    }

    operator snmp_pdu* () const {
        return impl_;
    }

    ~snmp_pdu_proxy() {
        if(impl_) {
            snmp_free_pdu(impl_);
        }
    } 
private:
    snmp_pdu_proxy& operator=(const snmp_pdu_proxy&);
    snmp_pdu* impl_;
};


int main()
{
    snmp_pdu_proxy ptr = snmp_pdu_proxy(0);

    snmp_pdu_proxy p2 = ptr.move();

    ptr = p2.move();

    foo(ptr);
}
```

Comment: There's another way to accomplish this without naming a new deleter. If the deleter type is specified as `decltype(&snmp_free_pdu)`, then the function can be passed directly to the `unique_ptr` c'tor as a second parameter.

Comment: @StoryTeller While true, IMHO it's a little more cryptic. There are many ways to skin this cat, and I have used them all. But in the end I find that creating a class for a specific job is easier to document and explain to colleagues.

Comment: I can see your point. Mine was more about avoiding incidental types. I suppose another big bonus of yours is the ability to specify `noexcept`

Comment: @StoryTeller types are cheap. I try to use one type represent one state or job.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++03, then you can't use `unique_ptr` for sure. However, this doesn't justify using `auto_ptr`. It's a horrible construct and is semantically  full of problems. For example, it's copyable, and a copy operation *moves* the object under it. I can't even start to describe how many problems that will cause.

Just create your own class that will do the deallocation for you with RAII. It's much simpler than you think. Here are a few examples:

1. On my blog [I described a few ways to do this](https://blog.afach.de/?p=695), even with C++03.
2. This is a [SmartHandle](https://git.afach.de/samerafach/SmartHandle) class that deallocates anything (unfortunately it's C++11). I use it for HDF5. You can change it to fit C++03 with a functor.
3. [This is a shared_ptr implementation](https://git.afach.de/samerafach/SharedPtr-cpp03) that supports detaching/releasing an object (it's not thread-safe). I created this for a project that works with gcc 4.3.

Take a look at these, and you'll get the idea. You can modify these examples to match your needs.

Good luck!