# Using automatic deduction with unique_ptr and custom deleter

Tags: c++, c++17, unique-ptr, type-deduction

I'm currently using a C library that defines a number of data types, all of which need to have their lifetimes managed by the user. There are a number of functions defined in this fashion:

```
int* create() {
    return new int();
}

void destroy(int* i) {
    delete i;
}
```

Most of these don't need to be accessed after creation. They simply need to exist. Because of this, I'm trying to manage them using `unique_ptr`'s declared in the scope of which I need them to live.

This is how such a declaration looks like:

```
// Note that I'm avoiding writing the type's name manually.
auto a = std::unique_ptr<std::decay_t<decltype(*create())>, decltype(&destroy)>{create(), &destroy};
```

But this is overly verbose, so I encapsulated it in a utility function template:

```
template<typename T>
auto make_unique_ptr(T* p, void (*f)(T*)) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(f)>(p, f);
}
```

Which is used this way:

```
auto b = make_unique_ptr(create(), &destroy);
```

This looks nice, but introduces a non-standard function that has no real purpose other than being syntactic sugar for some declarations. My colleagues may not even know it exists and end up creating other versions of it with different names.

[c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) Introduced [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction). I thought this is the perfect solution to my problem: A standard way to deduce all those types without resorting to user-defined wrappers. So I tried this:

```
auto c = std::unique_ptr{create(), &destroy};
```

As is the rule with C++ compilers and templates, this fails with a several lines long error message. Here are the relevant parts:

```
(...): error: class template argument deduction failed:
 auto c = std::unique_ptr{create(), &destroy};
                                            ^
(...): note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, class _Dp> 
unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer, typename std::remove_reference<_Dp>::type&&)-> std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>'
       unique_ptr(pointer __p,
       ^~~~~~~~~~
(...): note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
(...): note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Tp'
     auto c = std::unique_ptr{create(), &destroy};
                                                ^
```

*Theoretically*, I could add a deduction guide to handle this:

```
namespace std {

template<typename T>
unique_ptr(T* p, void (*f)(T*)) -> unique_ptr<T, decltype(f)>;

}
```

And it does work at least on my version of gcc, but the standard doesn't like it very much:

> #### [namespace.std]
>
> [1](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#1) Unless otherwise specified, the behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std.
>
> [4](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#4) The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it declares
>       (...)
>       [4.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#4.4)  - a deduction guide for any standard library class template.

There's also some problems related to differentiating between pointers and arrays, but let's ignore that.

**Finally, the question(s):** Is there any other way to 'help' `std::unique_ptr` (or maybe `std::make_unique`) to deduce the correct type when using custom deleters? Just in case this is an XY problem, is there any solutions I didn't think of for lifetime management of those types (perhaps `std::shared_ptr`)? If both of those answers are a negative, is there any improvements on [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) I should be looking forward to, that solve this issue?

[Feel free to test the above examples at Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ae990ace857a4db)

Comment: FWIW, unless you need to change the deleters at runtime, don't use a function pointer deleter like this. Without it, with an explicit type, `sizeof(unique_ptr<T>) == sizeof(T*)`. With it, `sizeof(unique_ptr<T>) == sizeof(T*) + sizeof(deleter)`, which is twice the size in this case

Comment: Why not a `make_library_type_nnn()` that returns the right `unique_ptr` and calls the right `create` function?

Comment: @NathanOliver IMHO, it doesn't scale very well. There are tons (Over 100) of those types, and most have multiple ways to be created.

Comment: @Justin Thanks for the info. It maybe doesn't matter that much (The actual structures are a bit more complex than a single `int`). I may have to measure the difference to be sure, but that's a lot of work that I'm kind of trying to avoid right now.

Comment: @CássioRenan It does matter. The structures might be complex, but suddenly your `unique_ptr`s are twice the size. If you have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`, suddenly half of the memory is wasted in that vector. It's not too hard to write a custom deleter, and you can even write one which takes the function pointer to the deleter as a template argument

Comment: @Justin Like Cássio Renan said, it might not matter. A solution that saves memory is favorable to one that doesn't if all other things are equal. But all things are not equal if you include the work necessary to convert from one to the other. Developer time is a finite resource just like memory (and much more expensive) and you're exchanging one for the other. You can't assume the trade-off always favors computer memory.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, but my point is that developer time is minimal here. It's remarkably easy to write a custom deleter and use it all over the place. Of course, if you have to write it for each deleter function, that's not worth it, but you can generalize it and write it once.

Comment: `template<auto f>using deleter_t = std::integral_constant< std::decay_t<decltype(f)>, f >; template<auto f> constexpr deleter_t<f> deleter{}`; now `unique_ptr<T, deleter_t<destroy>>` is the cost-free deleter you want.

Comment: @Justin I see your point, but François  basically stated my concern better than I could have worded myself. I would need to write a custom deleter for each of the types in the library. I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend writing custom deleters rather than using function pointers. Using the function pointer would make all the `unique_ptr`s twice the size for no reason.

Instead, write a deleter templated on a function pointer:

```
template <auto deleter_f>
struct Deleter {
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T* ptr) const
    {
        deleter_f(ptr);
    }
};
```

Or, as [*Yakk - Adam Nevraumont* mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252087/using-automatic-deduction-with-unique-ptr-and-custom-deleter/51252607#comment89483783_51252087):

```
template <auto deleter_f>
using Deleter = std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<decltype(deleter_f)>, deleter_f>;
```

Using it becomes pretty clean:

```
auto a = std::unique_ptr<int, Deleter<destroy>>{create()};
```

Although you might want to combine this with your `make_unique_ptr` function:

```
template <auto deleter_f, typename T>
auto create_unique_ptr(T* ptr)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter<deleter_f>>{ptr};
}

// Usage:
auto a = create_unique_ptr<destroy>(create());
```

Comment: _"Since the deleter is encoded in the type of the unique_ptr, your colleagues can't forget about it."_ won't they just `auto a = make_unqiue_ptr_by_colleague(create(), destroy);`?

Comment: @PasserBy Sure, but then their `a` would by incompatible with the functions written by the OP, which would hopefully prompt the colleague to investigate what's going on

Comment: i don't think I got that. Do you mean when passing off to another function? OP said these may exist only for RAII.

Comment: @PasserBy Ehh, good point. That point I made doesn't really do anything

Comment: I'm aware this (`make_unique_ptr_by_colleague`) is a very hard problem to solve. Yakk's answer helps a lot with that, but as I suspect I may not be able to implement it, I'll probably end up doing this instead. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

A type as a value:

```
template<class T>
struct tag_t {};
template<class T>
constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
```

A value as a type:

```
template<auto f>
using val_t = std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<decltype(f)>, f>;
template<auto f>
constexpr val_t<f> val{};
```

Note that `val<some_function>` is an empty type that can be invoked in a `constexpr` context with `()` and it will call `some_function`.  It can also store `int`s or whatever, but we are going to use it to store function pointers statelessly.

Now let's have fun:

```
namespace factory {
  // This is an ADL helper that takes a tag of a type
  // and returns a function object that can be used
  // to allocate an object of type T.
  template<class T>
  constexpr auto creator( tag_t<T> ) {
    return [](auto&&...args){
      return new T{ decltype(args)(args)... };
    };
  }
  // this is an ADL helper that takes a tag of a type
  // and returns a function object that can be used
  // to destroy that type
  template<class T>
  constexpr auto destroyer( tag_t<T> ) {
    return std::default_delete<T>{};
  }

  // This is a replacement for `std::unique_ptr`
  // that automatically finds the destroying function
  // object using ADL-lookup of `destroyer(tag<T>)`.
  template<class T>
  using unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr< T, decltype(destroyer(tag<T>)) >; // ADL magic here

  // This is a replacement for std::make_unique
  // that uses `creator` and `destroyer` to find
  // function objects to allocate and clean up
  // instances of T.
  template<class T, class...Args>
  unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&...args) {
    // ADL magic here:
    return unique_ptr<T>( creator( tag<T> )(std::forward<Args>(args)...) );
  }
}
```

ok, that is a framework.

Now let's imagine you have some library.  It has a type in it.  It needs super secret special sauce to create and destroy instances of it here:

```
namespace some_ns {
  struct some_type {
    int x;
  };
  some_type* create( int a, int b ) {
    return new some_type{ a+b }; // ooo secret
  }
  void destroy( some_type* foo ) {
    delete foo; // ooo special
  }
}
```

and we want to connect it up.  You reopen the namespace:

```
namespace some_ns {
  constexpr auto creator( tag_t<some_type> ) {
    return val<create>;
  }
  constexpr auto destoyer( tag_t<some_type> ) {
    return val<destroy>;
  }
}
```

and we are done.

`factory::unique_ptr<some_ns::some_type>` is the right type to store a unique ptr to `some_type`.  To create it you just `factory::make_unique<some_ns::some_type>( 7, 2 )` and you get a unique ptr of the correct type with a destroyer lined up, with zero memory overhead, and the call to the destroyer function involving no indirection.

Basically sweep `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` for `factory::unique_ptr` and `factory::make_unique`, then line up the creator/destroyer ADL helpers to make all unique ptrs to a given type just do the right thing.

Test code:

```
auto ptr = factory::make_unique<some_ns::some_type>( 2, 3 );
std::cout << ptr->x << "=5\n";
std::cout << sizeof(ptr) << "=" << sizeof(std::unique_ptr<some_ns::some_type>) << "\n";
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0b13a61e15330be).

This has zero runtime overhead over writing custom unique ptr types.  If you don't overload `creator` or `destroyer` for a `tag_t<X>` in `X`'s namespace (or in `namespace factory`), `factory::make_unique` returns a bog standard `std::unique_ptr<X>`.  If you do, it injects compile-time information how to destroy it.

By default `factory::make_unique<X>` uses `{}` initialization so it works with aggregates.

The `tag_t` system is to enable ADL-based customization of `factory::make_unique` and `factory::unique_ptr`.  It is useful elsewhere too.  End users don't have to know about it, they just need to know you use `factory::unique_ptr` and `factory::make_unique` always.

Searching for `std::make_unique` and `std::unique_ptr` should find you cases where someone is violating this rule.  Eventually (you hope) they'll notice all unique pointers are `factory::unique_ptr` instead of `std`.

The magic to add a type to the system is short enough and easy enough to copy that people can do it without having to understand ADL.  I'd include a paragraph marked "you don't need to know this, but this is how this works" in comments somewhere.

This is possibly overdone; I was just thinking how I'd handle distributed traits and destruction/creation in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) with some of the new features.  I haven't tried this in production, so there may be unrevealed problems.

Comment: This... May actually be doable. Oh, the magic of namespaces: Replacing some `using std::unique_ptr` with `using factory::unique_ptr` (And deprecating `make_unique_ptr`, which I would already do anyway) is much simpler than trying to find each single use. It's still a lot of work (defining all those tagged creators and destroyers) and it does have some problems (forgetting to create a tagged destroyer when you should will cause UB. Oops.), so I'll do my due dilligence.

Comment: @cassio it is easyish to make having a creator but no destroyer be a hard error.  The default creator just has to return a non-lambda; then static assert in the default destroyer that the creator is a default one.

Answer (score 2):

You are overcomplicating things. [Simply specialize `std::default_delete` for your custom types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50957671/3204551), and you can use a vanilla `std::unique_ptr`.

A shame that `std::shared_ptr` doesn't use the same customization-point, there you will have to supply the deleter explicitly.

Comment: What a coincidence. I was actually looking at the linked answer just now, since it popped up on the main page. Good stuff! I actually completely forgot about being able to specialize `::std` classes for custom types (Or even about `std::default_delete`, for that matter). Guess I have a lot to learn, still.

Comment: Having said that, I'm probably not implementing this, unfortunately, as it suffers from the same problems I'm having with Yakk's answer. It doesn't solve the type deduction problem (To be fair, all of the other answers also focused more on the deleters than on the deduction, which is fine by me), and forgetting to specialize `std::default_delete` when I should will cause UB. I **really** don't want to write over 100 boilerplate specializations just to prettify some RAII types.

Comment: You know, the preprocessor is *excellent* to write those specializations for you. You just give it the type and destroy-function. If you are feeling fancy and want to also specialize make_unique and make_shared, add the create-function too. That's writing it out once for the macro, one line for each type invoking the macro, and one line undefining the macro.

Comment: Also, a program calling [`std::default_delete::operator()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete) with an incomplete type is ill-formed. So, if the library-implementer ran with that, [the compiler will complain](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddac2dbcea136791) if the specializations aren't provided.

Comment: Yes, using the CPP would be my approach, but writing those lines isn't really the problem. There isn't exactly a list of types that I could use: I would have to dig through the documentation and some headers to find them. I would probably miss some, and would have to keep mantaining this list in case new types are introduced. About your other comment: I didn't get it: by the time I use them, all types are already complete. Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is use a `using` statement to introduce an alias for `std::unique_ptr<T, void (*)(T*)>` like

```
template<typename T>
using uptr = std::unique_ptr<T, void (*)(T*)>;
```

Then you could use it like

```
auto u = uptr<int>{create(), &destroy};
```

Comment: Isn't this also introducing another obscure identifier just for the sake of this purpose? As in, what OP doesn't want?

Comment: Better to use a different customization-point and avoid this mess completely.