# Can I succintly declare std::unique_ptr with custom deleter?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I am dealing with C types which have a `new_` and `free_` methods associated.

The type signature of `new_` may vary, but the `free_` is always a `void free_something(something*);`

Currently, I am declaring my `unique_ptr`s this way, which seems overly verbose:

```
std::unique_ptr<qdr_link_t, decltype(&free_qdr_link_t)> link{new_qdr_link_t(), free_qdr_link_t};
```

Can I do this with less ceremony, somehow? I saw a neat solution for a situation when my deallocator is the `std::free()` function, at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43626234/1047788. I tried to create a version where I could parameterize the deallocator, but I got nowhere with it.

The best I could think of was to create a macro from the above declaration.

Comment: I have multiple types like this, and for each type, I have a `type * new_type(...)` and `void free_type(void)`. So yes to that. There aren't multiple `new_` with same name but different signature, because they are all declared in C and that does not permit overloading.

Comment: How does `void free_type(void)` know what to free?  Is the thing to be freed stored in a global?

Comment: Silly me, the signature for free_ functions are `void free_type(*type)`. Sorry for getting it wrong previously.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252087/using-automatic-deduction-with-unique-ptr-and-custom-deleter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the language do the hard work!

```
#include <memory>

struct qdr_link_t;
qdr_link_t* new_qdr_link_t();
void free_qdr_link_t(qdr_link_t*);

template <typename T, typename Deleter>
auto make_unique_ptr(T* raw, Deleter deleter)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>(raw, deleter);
}

//std::unique_ptr<qdr_link_t, decltype(&free_qdr_link_t)> link{new_qdr_link_t(), free_qdr_link_t};
auto link = make_unique_ptr(new_qdr_link_t(), free_qdr_link_t);
```

Add `std::forward` to taste (if you care).

---

For C++11, you'll need to add the trailing return type `-> std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>` to `make_unique_ptr`, or just put that in the "normal" return type.

Comment: It is a poor software engineering solution in terms of the size of `std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>`. Each such a smart-pointer stores a pointer to the very same function, which is unnecessary.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin This is how `unique_ptr` works. It would be possible to wrap `free_qdr_link_t` in some callable type that "hardcodes" it and thus takes no runtime storage. But is there really a need for such complexity here? The best software engineering solution is the simplest, unless otherwise required.

Comment: If one took the trouble of using C++, that means they want an efficient rather than easy solution. For easy solution they can use Python.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Writing the most complex solution possible for the "efficiency" of not storing a single function pointer, when you don't need to, is not the purpose of writing C++. "Use Python instead then" is... a silly suggestion, to be honest. C++ is only "trouble" if you insist on making it so.

Comment: My primary criterion is simplicity of use. I have large number of various C structs like `qd_link_t` in a program and I want to use scoped pointers for them in unittests written in C++. Saving memory on the pointers is not worth it, if it complicates usage at the callsite or if I have to manually declare wrapper callable type. The tests have much worse perf problems than this.

Comment: Lol, Python is that "much worse perf problem" I alluded to before. The app under test is written in a mix of C and embedded Python. Any unittest has to first initialize Python, to do anything "useful".

Comment: IMO, you wasted more ink defending your sub-optimal solution, then ink required to write an efficient solution. Feel free to disagree.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I wouldn't have had to if you hadn't wasted "ink" on challenging a perfectly reasonable, working solution that the OP is happy with  Feel free to write a more complex competing answer. ‍♂️ Have a good one.

Comment: (I'd actually appreciate something more "optimal", provided that it will be as simple to use as `auto link = make_unique_ptr(new_qdr_link_t(), free_qdr_link_t);` is. Any extra complexity can be hidden behind a function call, or other such C++ mechanism.)

Comment: @user7610 Not really. At the very least you'd have to create a new type somewhere to wrap `free_qdr_link_t`, and do that for every other free-ing function you have too. It doesn't scale well. If that were so, I'd have shown it. This way, in my view, has the right balance of simplicity, readability, maintainability, usability, performance and extensibility.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using following:

```
template <auto fptr>
struct Caller {
    template <class... Args>
    auto
    operator()(Args&&... args) noexcept
    {
        return fptr(std::forward<Args...>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Example usage:

```
using qdr_freer = Caller<free_qdr_link_t>;

using unique_qdr_ptr = std::unique_ptr<qdr_link_t, qdr_freer>;

[[nodiscard]] unique_qdr_ptr
make_qdr_unique()
{
    return unique_qdr_ptr{new_qdr_link_t()};
}
```

This implementation uses C++17 features though, so it requires a few changes to work in C++11.

---

Note that although `Caller` may seem like a good fit with `std::free`, they are strictly speaking not compatible because `std::free` is a standard library function not designated as "addressable".

Comment: Fixed-signature `template<void(*F)()>` is one option; another one is `template<class T, T F>`.