# Unique ptr with custom allocator and deleter

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr

I'm trying to use a unique ptr in the following scenario:

```
MyClass *pMC = NULL;
if ( !MyCustomAlloc(void ** (&pMC), sizeof(MyClass) )
{
    return false;
}
// do things
if (something else fails)
{
    MyCustomDelete(pMC);
    return false;
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is have convert this to a unique ptr so that the MyCustomDelete doesn't need to be called explicitly.

What I don't get is how I can retain the above structure and still return the appropriate values.

```
unique_ptr<MyClass, void (*)(void**, size_t)> pMC( <b>Not Sure What Goes Here</b> , MyCustomDelete);
```

- If I put MyCustomAlloc as the 1st arg, how will it's failure be detected?
- Or if I do the following then pMC will be initialized to NULL, but how can the custom deleter be set?
  `unique_ptr<MyClass, void (*)(void**, size_t)> pMC;`

  Can I do something like `pMC.set(MyCustomDelter)`?

Comment: `MyCustomAlloc(void ** (&pMC), sizeof(MyClass)` leads to undefined behaviour in Standard C++ (you cannot alias some other pointer as `void *`) . It would be better to make the function be `template<typename T> T *MyCustomAlloc();` or similar

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053351/how-do-i-use-a-custom-deleter-with-a-stdunique-ptr-member) ?

Comment: Thanks. Trying it out. Will report how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a delete class which overloads the () operator and then pass this class as the 2nd template argument.

`typedef struct MyClassDeleter
    {
        void operator()(MyClass* p)
        {
            MyCustomDelete(p);
        }
    }
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass, MyClassDeleter> pMC;`