# How to initialize unique_ptr from raw C heap memory pointer?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, raw-pointer

I am using a function (which is part of a library) which returns a raw `uint8_t*` pointer to some memory which has been allocated on the heap and holds image pixel data. The caller of this function is responsible for calling `free` on the pointer.

My code where I call this function has many branches with early termination and I therefore would need to call `free(buffer)` at many points. I think it would be better if I could wrap the buffer in a `unique_ptr` so that when it falls out of scope, the memory is automatically freed.

How can I achieve this?

For reference, the function decleration looks something like this: `uint8_t* getFrame()` (I already know the width, height, and num channels of the image and thus the length of the buffer);

Comment: Is any of the wisdom contained within [How do I use a custom deleter with a std::unique_ptr member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053351/how-do-i-use-a-custom-deleter-with-a-stdunique-ptr-member) of any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty simple to do! The template for `std::unique_ptr` looks like this:

```
template<class T, class Deleter>
class unique_ptr;
```

And the Deleter is used to clean up the value pointed to by the `unique_ptr` when it falls out of scope. We can write one to use `free` really simply!

```
struct DeleteByFree {
    void operator()(void* ptr) const {
        free(ptr);
    }
};

template<class T>
using my_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, DeleteByFree>;
```

Now, whenever you use an instance of `my_unique_ptr`, it'll call C's `free()` function to clean itself up!

```
int main(){
    // This gets cleaned up through `free`
    my_unique_ptr<int> ptr {(int*)malloc(4)}; 
}
```

Comment: Simple and clean. Great answer. Glad I didn't just dupe-hammer the question shut.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the fast solution!

Comment: With your example above, would I need to do `my_unique_ptr<uint8>frame {buffer}`; or `my_unique_ptr<uint8[]>frame {buffer}`; ?

Comment: i would use `uint8[]` just so that other people understand it's a buffer and not a pointer to an individual `uint8`, however unlike `delete`, which has optimizations for individually allocated objects, `free` makes no distinctions between a single object and an array of objects

Comment: Awesome thanks @J.AntonioPerez