# Why I'm getting "invalid use of incomplete type" error when I change raw pointer to unique_pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, sdl-2, smart-pointers

I'm making some SDL2 wrappers in C++. Like this:

```
/* header file */
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
#include <memory>

class SDL2_Music {
 public:
  ~SDL2_Music() { free(); }
  bool loadMusic(const std::string& path);
  bool play(int loops = -1);
  // more methods
 private:
  void free();
  Mix_Music* music_ = nullptr;
};

/* cpp file */
void SDL2_Music::free() {
  if (music_ != nullptr) {
    Mix_FreeMusic(music_);
    music_ = nullptr;
  }
}
bool SDL2_Music::loadMusic(const std::string& path) {
  free();
  music_ = Mix_LoadMUS(path.c_str()); // this returns a Mix_Music*
  if (music_ == nullptr) {
    ktp::logSDLError("Mix_LoadMUS");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
// more stuff
```

This works fine, but I want to get rid of the raw pointer, so I can also get rid of the `free()` method and the `dtor` invoking it (yes, I'm reading about the rule of 0). So I made the following changes:

```
/* header file */
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
#include <memory>

class SDL2_Music {
 public:
  bool loadMusic(const std::string& path);
  bool play(int loops = -1);
  // more methods
 private:
  std::unique_ptr<Mix_Music> music_ = nullptr; 
};

/* cpp file */
bool SDL2_Music::loadMusic(const std::string& path) {
  music_ = std::make_unique<Mix_Music>(Mix_LoadMUS(path.c_str()));
  if (music_ == nullptr) {
    ktp::logSDLError("Mix_LoadMUS");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
// more stuff
```

When I try to compile (GCC) I get:

> "C:\Users\not_bjarne\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\8.1.0\include\c++\bits\unique_ptr.h|831|error:
> invalid use of incomplete type 'struct _Mix_Music'"

And codeblocks points me to `unique_ptr.h`, which I obviously didn't tried to "fix".

Comment: You should tell us the details of line 831 of that file.  That will probably answer the question of what is going on.

Comment: Sure, it reads `{ return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }`. But the problems seems to be what Brian is telling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `Mix_Music` is an incomplete type and the correct way to free a `Mix_Music` object is to call the `Mix_FreeMusic` function. You cannot dispose of it the way you would a C++ object, namely by using `delete`. `delete` would attempt to call the destructor (which cannot be done in this context, since the type is incomplete here) and would assume that the object was allocated by `new` and return the memory to the same pool where `new` got it from. The way SDL allocates the object is an implementation detail, so you must let SDL deallocate the object itself as well, to ensure it is done properly.

`std::unique_ptr` can be used for this purpose, but requires a custom deleter. The default deleter will call `delete`, which should not be done here. The error you are seeing is because `delete p;` is ill-formed (where `p` has type `Mix_Music*`) because of the incompleteness. You must ensure that the custom deleter calls `Mix_FreeMusic`. You can see how to use custom deleters here: [How do I use a custom deleter with a std::unique_ptr member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053351/how-do-i-use-a-custom-deleter-with-a-stdunique-ptr-member)