# std::unique_ptr with custom deleter: regular vs array type

Tags: c++, memory, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Say I have two functions:

```cpp
const char* get_string(int id);
bool free_string(const char* str);
```

I want to write a `std::unique_ptr` wrapper for them.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51274008/2604492) I created the following:

```cpp
template <auto fn>
struct deleter_from_fn {
    template <typename T>
    constexpr void operator()(T* arg) const {
        fn(arg);
    }
};

using my_string_unique_ptr =
    std::unique_ptr<const char, deleter_from_fn<free_string>>;
```

But then I thought, it's not a pointer to a `const char`, it's a pointer to an array of characters. So I replaced it with the following:

```cpp
using my_string_unique_ptr =
    std::unique_ptr<const char[], deleter_from_fn<free_string>>;
```

Both seem to work just fine. So my questions are:

- Which variant is preferred?
- Is there any actual difference between the two variants?

Comment: You only *need* to differentiate between `char*` and `char[]` when you are letting `unique_ptr` do the deletion.  Since you have a custom deleter that doesn't matter and is an opinion of style.

Comment: `unique_ptr<T>` holds a `new`'ed `T*` pointer and calls `delete` on it. `unique_ptr<T[]>` holds a `new[]`'ed `T*` pointer and calls `delete[]` on it. `unique_ptr<T, deleter>` and `unique_ptr<T[], Deleter>` both hold a `Deleter::pointer` (if defined) or `T*` pointer and call `Deleter()` on it.

Comment: "*it's not a pointer to a `const char`, it's a pointer to an array of characters*" - technically, it is actually a pointer to the 1st `const char` in the array, not a pointer to the array itself. A pointer to a `const char[]` array would have the type `const char (*)[N]` instead (where `N` is the size of the array). But that is not what `get_string()` is returning. So `unique_ptr<const char, Deleter>` would be more appropriate. But you can use `unique_ptr<const char[], Deleter>` to make your type more descriptive, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main differences between `unique_ptr<T, Deleter>` and `unique_ptr<T[], Deleter>` are:

- The array version has an `operator[]`, the single version has `operator*` and `operator->`. This emphasises the fact that there isn't just a single element, since it's more difficult to get a reference to just the first element.
- When constructing the array version from a differently typed pointer, it will check if `U(*)[]` is convertible to `T(*)[]` instead of simply `U*` to `T*`. This is not very useful for `T = const char`, but for class types it prevents casting `derived_type[N]` to `base_type[N]`, which probably won't work right (in terms of pointer arithmetic/freeing).

Use the array version if you have an array.